# Show / Hide (toggle) Splash Screen during startup

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I have assigned a unique GRUB_BACKGROUND='someimage.png' and it works fine.

However, at times I need to troubleshoot issues during boot time.  I need to be able to press a hotkey to see the actual boot loading text.

I have tried ESC, Right Ctrl-S and many other combinations but nothings working.  I cannot locate the correct key combination to accomplish this.

What sayeth the group ?

Using Ubuntu (Xubuntu flavor) 18.04

Thanks.

J @ CompuMatter

Comment: Does this help ? https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/700522

Comment: I'm afraid not.  That post has more to do the initial grub setting.

My need is different. In my case yes I wish to show the splash screen - however - I want to be able to toggle the splash screen off during startup so I can see the loading text "at will".

During the shutdown process this is easily done with the Esc key.  However, during boot this is having no effect.  So it is impossible to debug startup processes with a splash screen that cannot be toggled.

I do not want to change grub and loose the splash screen permanently - just desire to temporarily toggle it off during boot.